# Calculate the length of a polar curve

Tags: polar-coordinates, arc-length

> Calculate the length of the polar curve $$\theta (r)=\frac{1}{2}\left( r+\frac{1}{r}\right)$$ from r = 1 to r = 3.

I understand mostly how to get the length of a polar curve by:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt[]{(f(\theta ))^{2}+(f'(\theta ))^{2}} \ d\theta $$

But in this exercise i dont get how to do it. Maybe i need to write the function $\theta (r)$ in terms of $\theta$

Any ideas or hints? Thanks

Comment: Instead use $\int ds=\int_1^3\sqrt{1+r^2(d\theta/dr)^2}dr$.

Comment: @J.G. Possible typo in $r^2$ factor?

Comment: @J.G. Very nice.

Comment: Consider instead a parametric equation $r(t)=t~,~\theta(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)$. Do you know how to get arc length of a parametric equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: @zkutch No, $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$. If you try it, you'll see why this problem was invented with this specific $\theta(r)$.

Comment: @J.G. I think your reputation is enough to see my deleted answer 10h ago. Analogically in same way as wrote above K.defaoite I use simple parametric representation for $(r,\theta)$ plane, which gives exactly same integral as yours, but without $r^2$ factor. Both cannot be true. So, for everybody will be helpful if you elaborate your variant in more details.

Comment: @zkutch Your calculation assumes $ds^2=dr^2(1+(d\theta/dr)^2)=dr^2+d\theta^2$, which is incorrect; it should be $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2$. A "simple parametric representation" doesn't require the metric tensor in $ds^2=g_{ab}dx^adx^b$ to be the Kronecker delta.

Comment: @J.G. I think you didn’t pay enough attention to my words about choosing a plane, so your assessment may be a little hasty. I expressed my position in more detail in my answer and I think that both positions have the right to live, though your answer is probably more in line with what the questioner wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As OP states "polar curve", then we can imagine it as curve on polar plane, or curve on Cartesian plane in polar coordinates. So, we can do it in 2 ways:

1. Considering it as usual parametrical representation of curve **on plane** $(\boldsymbol r, \boldsymbol\theta)$ and considering $r$ as parameter we have $$\left(\frac{ds}{dr}\right)^2 =\left(\frac{dr}{dr}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d \theta}{dr}\right)^2$$
   So, length can be calculated as
   $$\int\limits_{1}^{3}\sqrt{1+\theta'^2(r)}dr $$
2. Considering **on plane** $(\boldsymbol x, \boldsymbol y)$ and taking polar representation of curve by $x =r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$. Using in last formulas $\theta = \theta(r)$ we can calculate
   $$\frac{dx}{dr} = \cos \theta - r \frac{d\theta}{dr} \sin \theta$$
   and
   $$\frac{dy}{dr} = \sin \theta + r \frac{d\theta}{dr} \cos \theta$$
   Using obtained we have
   $$\left(\frac{ds}{dr}\right)^2 =\left(\frac{dx}{dr}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dr}\right)^2 =\\
   =\left(\ \cos \theta - r \frac{d\theta}{dr} \sin \theta \right)^2 + \left(\ \sin \theta + r \frac{d\theta}{dr} \cos \theta \right)^2 =\\
   =1+ r^2\left(\frac{d\theta}{dr}\right)^2$$
   and length can be calculate as integral
   $$\int\limits_{1}^{3}\sqrt{1+r^2\theta'^2(r)}dr$$

Comment: Option 1 is inappropriate. It amounts to saying, "no matter what coordinates we work in, treat them like they're Cartesian". The resulting "length" between two points is then dependent on the choice of coordinates. The whole point of computing arclengths is for the length to be a coordinate-independent concept, computed with whichever choice of coordinates is most *convenient*.

Comment: (Fun fact, though: option 1's treatment of the circle $r=a$ gives it a circumference of $2\pi$, regardless of $a$.)

Comment: Can you explain me this notation? Any reference? $\left(\frac{ds}{dr}\right)^2 =\left(\frac{dx}{dr}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dr}\right)^2 $

Comment: @Pedro Errazuriz. Look at John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961), pages 243-245. , Paul Dawkins Calculus_III, 2018, from page 229. More light version Stewart, James - Calculus-Cengage Learning (2016), pages 587-588. Feel free to ask more when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my comment, since $rd\theta/dr=\tfrac12(r-\tfrac1r)$, $\int ds=\int_1^3\tfrac12(r+\tfrac1r)dr=2+\tfrac12\ln3$.

Comment: Thank you. Another question, how do you get the formula from your first comment?

Comment: @PedroErrazuriz See e.g. [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/polararclength.aspx) or [here](http://www.vias.org/calculus/07_trigonometric_functions_10_01.html).